# Render Just Text of Link in Sitecore for Open Graph

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

I'm hoping to add OpenGraph Data to our templates and want to get the text of a link from a template field and then put it in the open graph section.

I do not have access to the source code to use code behind.

Here is what I have:

```
<meta content="<sc:link field="Open Graph URL" runat="server" />" property="og:url" />
```

I was trying to use a link template field so it wouldn't have to be manually typed as text. When this renders I get the whole formatted anchor tag, I just want the URL.

Comment: I deleted your image link since it was not pointing to an actual image. Please add correct one.

Comment: Thanks - I don't have a high enough reputation to post an image. I think the question still works without it.

Comment: If you give me a link I can edit it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<meta content="<%= ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph URL"]).GetFriendlyUrl() %>" property="og:url" />
```

Comment: Very helpful because it stopped the template from returning a 500 server error since I was so far off previously.  The result of this is my content path, not the fully-qualified URL. How do I get the fully qualified URL?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now using .GetFriendlyUrl().

Comment: Appreciate the update - when I change the code to reflect the update, it causes a 500 error.  I researched that GetFriendlyUrl() was deprecated, since we are on Sitecore 7.0 I'm wondering if that is the issue.  

I'm happy to try and learn all this on my own, but I can't seem to find good guides for doing things in Sitecore without XSL or code behind.

Comment: The GetFriendlyUrl method on LinkField is not deprecated. A method by same name at Item.Paths.GetFriendlyUrl is however deprecated, maybe it is this method you are referring to.
What is the exception?

Comment: When I put in
<meta content="<%= ((Sitecore.Data.Fields.LinkField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields["Open Graph URL"]).GetFriendlyUrl() %>" property="og:url" />, I receive a 500 page, with no error given. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Are you sure that the item has the field?
If you set customErrors mode="Off" in web.config, you should get more details on the error.